# why we need both Look Ahead symbol and read ahead symbol in Compiler

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

well i was reading some common concepts regarding parsing in compiler..i came across `look ahead` and read `ahead symbol`  i search and read about them but i am stuck like why we need both of them ? would be grateful for any kind suggestion

> Lookahead symbol: when node being considered in parse tree is for a terminal, and the
> terminal matches lookahead symbol,then we advance in both parse and
> input
>
> read aheadsymbol:  lexical analyzer may need to read some character
> before it can decide on the token to be returned

Comment: @GuyCoder They are not saying the same thing, and these are well-known facts of compiler construction.

Comment: @user207421 OK, then can you explain the differences with examples. I read the current two answers and they don't help me understand the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these is about parsing and refers to the next *token* to be produced by the lexical scanner. The other one, which is less formal, is about lexical analysis and refers to the next *character* in the input stream. It should be clear which is which.

Note that while most parsers only require a single lookahead token, it is not uncommon for lexical analysis to have to backtrack, which is equivalent to examining several unconsumed input characters.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got your question right.

Consider C.

It has several punctuators that begin the same way:

- `+`, `++`, `+=`
- `-`, `--`, `-=`, `->`
- `<`, `<=`, `<<`, `<<=`
- ...

In order to figure out which one it is when you see the first `+` or `-` or `<`, you need to look ahead one character in the input (and then maybe one more for `<<=`).

A similar thing can happen at a higher level:

```
{
  ident1 ident2;
  ident3;
  ident4:;
}
```

Here `ident1`, `ident3` and `ident4` can begin a declaration, an expression or a label. You can't tell which one immediately. You can consult your existing declarations to see if `ident1` or `ident3` is already known (as a type or variable/function/enumeration), but it's still ambiguous because a colon may follow and if it does, it's a label because it's permitted to use the same identifier for both a label and a type/variable/function/enumeration (those two name spaces do not intersect), e.g.:

```
{
  typedef int ident1;
  ident1 ident2; // same as int ident2
  int ident3 = 0;
  ident3; // unused expression of value 0
  ident1:; // unused label
  ident2:; // unused label
  ident3:; // unused label
}
```

So, you may very well need to look ahead a character or a token (or "unread" one) to deal with situations like these.

Comment: The only case in C where you need to look two characters ahead is when the next two characters are `..`. Since `..` is not a token but `...` is, you need to return a `.` token if the input is, say, `..0`. (That's a syntax error, but that's detected after preprocessing, and only if the tokens still exist at that point.) Every other prefix is either a complete token or can be extended by the next character. Eg., If `<<` is not followed by `=`, the token is `<<`.

Comment: @rici I don't see much difference between `...` and `<<=`, you still need to greedily consume three input characters to recognize the new token.

Comment: the difference is when it doesn't match. In the case of `...`, you need to backtrack to the first dot. If you can't backtrack, you need to peek two characters ahead, not just one. In the case of `<<=`, as soon as you see the second `<`, you can forget about the possibility of a `<` token (at least in C). So a single peek is always enough.